# Why this Javascrript Error Is coming at line 2 character 1

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have The Following Javascript Error 
"Line 2 Character 1" coming  in the entire app 
I have  researched Follwing thing in SOF  i have found this link .
[Javascript Line 1 Syntax error in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291081/javascript-line-1-syntax-error-in-ie)
So my JS script is  something like this

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var sv = "<?php echo $var1 ;>";
var sv1 = "<?php echo $var2 ;>";
var sv2 = "<?php echo $var3 ;>";
var sv3 = "<?php echo $var4 ;>";
var sv4 = "<?php echo $var5 ;>";
});
</script>
```

But when i put the same code under JSLINT it is saying "Problem at line 1 character 2: Expected 'html' and instead saw 'script'."
.How can I make by script corrected .Can any one please explain what iam doing wrong

Comment: What is the actual output? I'm assuming your PHP will be evaluated and change the javascript that is actually being run by the browser. use View source and show us that.

Comment: this will cause problems if your php vars have double quotes in them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't properly closing your PHP tags

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
var sv = "<?php echo $var1 ?>";
var sv1 = "<?php echo $var2 ?>";
var sv2 = "<?php echo $var3 ?>";
var sv3 = "<?php echo $var4 ?>";
var sv4 = "<?php echo $var5 ?>";
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare html tags first, and THEN you can start typing your script.
Wrap it in  tags.

You're also having some weird PHP tags there, they need to be finished with ?>, not ;>

Answer (score 0):

Are you sending the PHP directly to the browser? If not, we'll need to see the code as it appears to the browser. If there was a double quote being printed, for example, it would cause syntax errors.

Also, there shouldn't be whitespace between your type attribute and the = character.